# Using Win32::GuiTest to get data from grid display control (AfxWnd42s)

Tags: perl, winapi, gui-testing, win32gui

I'm currently writing some perl scripts to test one of our GUI applications.  I'm using perl's Win32::GuiTest as a foundation, and it's pretty functional for the most part.  However, I am now stuck trying to get data out of a grid control (not sure what the actual name of the widget is since this is supposed to be black-box testing).  Using WinSpy++, I can see that it's class is "AfxWnd42s", whatever that means.  I can get the window handle with this code:

```
#
# check that listed ports match the spec for this model
#
my @portgrids = FindWindowLike($win,undef,"AfxWnd42s");
if(not @portgrids){ die "can't find port grid"; }

for(@portgrids){
    my $styles = GetWindowLong($_,Win32::GuiTest::GWL_STYLE());
    my $text = WMGetText($_);
    $wintext = GetWindowText($_);
    printf("static w=%x, s=$wintext, style=%x text=<<$text>>\n",$_,$styles);
}
```

Neither text, nor wintext contain any value, even though there is data in the grid control.  I've tried a number of different options to GetWindowLong, but nothing seems to return anything about the contents of the grid.  Also, The windows I'm scanning have no children.  I'm stuck.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the code or the dev environment to build the application.  I can only go by what WinSpy++ tells me about the window components.

Comment: I've discovered that the actual component inherits from CUGCtrl, which is a third-party grid control.

Comment: Not a good sign.  According to this, it's impossible: http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/windows-programmer-win32/t-gettext-from-a-afxwnd42s-control-109502.html